# getting result from doopl in python

Tags: python-3.x, cplex, docplex, doopl

Hi I'm using doOPL in python.

The following is part of my code.

```
with create_opl_model(model="phase0.mod",data="prob1.dat") as opl:
    # tuple can be a list of tuples, a pandas dataframe...
    # Generate the problem and solve it.
    start_time = time.time()
    opl.mute()
    opl.run()
    print("obj:",opl.objective_value,", time:",(time.time() - start_time))
```

After running it, I would like to check the result of decision variable x

`opl.get_table('x')`

But it doesn't work saying expecting tupleset x was passed.

I'm looking forward your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `get_table()` will only work for tables (aka tuple sets) that you created *explicitly* in post-processing. So you have to create this table in post processing.

Consider this example definition of `x`:

```
range I = 1..2;
range J = 1..4;
dvar float+ x[I][J];
```

In post-processing, you can do

```
tuple R {
  int i;
  int j;
  float val;
}
{R} xResult = { <i,j,x[i][j]> | i in I, j in J };
```

With that you should be able to to `opl.get_table('xResult')` and in this table you should have all the triplets `(i, j, x[i][j])`.

Comment: You just saved my life! I really appreciate it!